# Are the following topological spaces locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to determine whether the following spaces are locally compact:
a) the slotted plane
b) the radial plane

For part a) I am almost certain that it is not compact, but not sure how to go about showing this.

Please show any steps to prove this or likewise, any counterexample to disprove.

Thanks!

Comment: Include the definitions in your comments. Mathematicians might not even agree on a definition of "local compactness".

Comment: @André: A very good idea in principle, but not really necessary here, since the spaces are Hausdorff: all of the usual definitions coincide.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: What spaces?... To be honest, I didn't even bother to look for the definitions of a "slotted plane" or a "radial plane"... Sorry if I am too picky... but it is just that I feel left out. :-)

Comment: @André: If you have Willard’s *General Topology*, the slotted plane is Exercise $4$C, and the radial plane is Exercise $3$A$(4)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You are very kind!! :-) Sorry for being pedantic... Keep up the great job and also being such a nice person! :-D

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For (a) you can show that if $U$ is a non-empty open set, then $U$ contains a line segment $L$. $L$ is a closed, discrete set in the whole space, and it has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. And $\operatorname{cl}U$ is separable, so by [Jones's lemma](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/jones-lemma/) it is not normal. It Hausdorff, however, so it cannot be compact; why?

For (b) you can use the same basic idea. First show that $\Bbb Q^2$ is dense in the radial plane. Then show that every circle is a closed, discrete set in the radial plane. Finally, use the fact that $\mathfrak{c}$ is not the supremum of countably many smaller cardinals to show that if $U$ is an open nbhd of a point $p$, then there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $U$ contains $\mathfrak{c}$ points of the circle of radius $2^{-n}$ centred at $p$. Then apply Jones's lemma and argue as before.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, however I am unfamiliar with Jones's Lemma and ideas from cardinals. Is there perhaps a more elementary way of going about this?

Comment: @LordVader007: Alternatively, you could use the Baire category theorem to show that $\operatorname{cl}U$ is not normal, by showing that the rational and irrational points on $L$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. I'll have to think more about the radial plane: that was actually the simplest argument that occurred to me.

Comment: @Brian, could you please explain why did you used the separabality of $\rm{cl} U$ instead of $U$?